# Workaround to return a list from a ComputedProperty function in NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I am converting my app to use NDB. I used to have something like this before:

```
@db.ComputedProperty
    def someComputedProperty(self, indexed=False):
      if not self.someCondition:
          return []
      src = self.someReferenceProperty
      list =  src.list1 + src.list2 + src.list3 + src.list4 \
              + [src.str1, src.str2]
      return map(lambda x:'' if not x else x.lower(), list)
```

As you can see, my method of generating the list is a bit complicated, I prefer to keep it this way. But when I started converting to NDB, I just replaced `@db.ComputedProperty` by `@model.ComputedProperty` but then I got this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Property someComputedProperty does not support <type 'list'> types.
```

I could see in `model.py` in ext.ndb that `ComputedProperty` inherits from `GenericProperty` where in the `_db_set_value` there are several if/else statements that handle value according to its type, except that there's no handling for `lists`

Currently it goes through the first condition and gives out that error when I return an empty list.

Is there a way to work around this and avoid the error?

Comment: Supplying `indexed=False` to your function in the first snippet has no effect on the indexing of your computed property. As Mohamed Khamis points out, if you don't want it indexed, though, there's no point storing it in the datastore in the first place - just use a regular @Property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This whole functionality can be done within a function, so it doesn't need to be a `ComputedProperty`. Use Computed Properties only when you want to do a computation that you might query for. A `ComputedProperty` can have its `indexed` flag set to `False` but then this means you won't be querying for it, and therefore don't really need to have it as a property.

```
def someComputedProperty(self):
  if not self.someCondition:
      return []
  src = self.someReferenceProperty
  list =  src.list1 + src.list2 + src.list3 + src.list4 \
          + [src.str1, src.str2]
  return map(lambda x:'' if not x else x.lower(), list)
```

Comment: This is true unless you intend to be able to write queries against this property... then you would need a ComputedProperty so that it is in the datastore.

Comment: Agree in general, but there might be the odd case where you just don't want to query for it, but want to be able to see it in datastore viewer.

Answer (score 13):

You need to set the repeated=True flag for your computed property in NDB. I don't think you can use the cute "@db.ComputedProperty" notation, you'll have to say:

```
def _computeValue(self):
    ...same as before...
someComputedProperty = ComputedProperty(_computeValue, repeated=True, indexed=False)
```