# NDB Query with Computed Property returns a blank list

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to query an ndb Model with a computed property, but it's returning an empty list. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895986/986415) suggests that I should be able to query computed properties and so do [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#intro). What am I doing wrong?

```
from django.template import defaultfilters
class Video(models.SfxModel):

  title = ndb.StringProperty()
  slug = ndb.ComputedProperty(
    lambda self: str(defaultfilters.slugify(self.title)) )
```

In Interactive Console

```
from app.lib.videos import Video

slug = Video.query().get().slug
print slug
# => "some-dasherized-string"
print Video.query(Video.slug == slug).fetch()
# => []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'issue' you are having is the [eventual consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Data_Consistency) given for non [ancestor queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Ancestor_Queries).
what you are seeing is completely normal for the high replication datastore. 
when you put an entity and query for it right after it could be that its not replicated over all datacenters so it could not be found.

if you want this to work you have to use entity groups by adding a parent to an entity.
this can be an entity key or a constructed key that does not belong to any stored entity.

this works:

```
class Video(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    slug  = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.title.replace(' ', '-'))

v = Video(parent = ndb.Key(Video, 'xxx'), title = 'foo bar') 
v.put()

print Video.query(Video.slug == v.slug, ancestor = ndb.Key(Video, 'xxx')).get()
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about why entity groups are important. Why would I want to declare a Video as a parent of my video entities? And if I did, which entity would be the parent? In your example code, is the `"xxx"` a placeholder or does it mean something?

Thanks for the quick response. Also, the code I showed above was in `dev_appserver`. Does that change anything?

Comment: this is how the datastore works with entity groups and eventual consistency. the parent is just a generated key. should take a look at the documentation i pointed you to. if you save an entity and query for it right after its not guaranteed to be returned by a non ancestor query right after. it the SDK is made to reflect the production evironment so you should expect this in production too. but it might 1 second after... take a look here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: but that does not mean you need to use ancestors at all. if you don't need to query for that specific entity right after it was created you will be fine working with eventual consistency.

Comment: >> the parent is just a generated key. Sorry I still don't understand this. I understand that to make an entity available immediately I should add it to an entity group, but is that the only purpose of ancestry? Also, my example showed a newly add `property` (as opposed to a newly added entity. I'm assuming new properties also follow the same principle of eventual consistency?

Comment: when you create an entity you can define the key yourself or let the system do that for you. you should take a deep look into the high replication datastore and entity groups. replication of new entities or modified properties follow the same rule. it has to be replicated to other datacenters. so yes it follows the same principle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002887/google-app-engine-entity-groups this might help

Comment: Thanks that question helped a lot.