# NDB query on computed property not evaluated correctly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm running into a strange problem. I think I'm not in the case of the [replication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302906/ndb-query-with-computed-property-returns-a-blank-list) but something similar.

I've this model that has a computed property

```
   status = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self._compute_status())
...
    def _compute_status(self):
        if self.canceled:
            return "CANCELED"
        course = self.course.get().course_type
        if course == "SCHEDULED":
            now = datetime.now()
            if now < self.start_date:
                return "UPCOMING"
            elif now > self.end_date:
                return "FINISHED"
        return "ONGOING"
```

Now, I query all the models and I do these two prints

```
print sessions[0]
print sessions[0].status
```

the results show diffrent values:

```
Session(key=Key('Session', 5302669702856704), canceled=False, course=Key('Course', 6605041225957376), created=datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 5, 13, 39, 56, 86329), day_no=None, end_date=datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 8, 9, 35), meta_data=None, name=u'asd', profile=None, session_type=u'JOINT', start_date=datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 7, 8, 50), status='UPCOMING', url=u'', week_no=None)
FINISHED
```

In the first print the `status=ONGOING` while in the second it's `FINISHED` as it supposed to be since the `end_date` is after today.

This has an implication on the query, since if I query for `status=='FINISHED'` it does not return the correct set of results.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Actually the docs says:

> Caution: ComputedProperties are not calculated on query, but rather on
>   put(). If you update a model's schema to include a ComputedProperty,
>   you should remember to update existing entities by loading and writing
>   them to the Datastore. See Updating Your Model's Schema for more
>   information.

but then, how can I perform the query? do I've to filter them by "hand"?

Answer (score 3):

You have to query by datetime property, because when you put this entity into the datastore -- the value is calculated based on current time, and when you're querying it -- the old value still used, but value is getting re-calculated when you touch this property.